# WordPress Customer Role users Redirect to home page for some reason

Tags: wordpress

I created a user profile page all users are fine but when a user with a customer role access the profile page its redirected to the home page, can anyone please check what this happening
please watch the video here
https://www.loom.com/share/fb2ab2644b9d4da5b41ab7a00e79faa8

Comment: Can you provide us with more detailed explanation and your code snippet(s) without which it'd be almost impossible to debug your code?

Comment: There is no code related to this no custom-coded though I shared a complete video for an explanation like I didn't use any code or script only plugins that I showed its weird issue, its only redirect user with role customer to home page when i try to access profile page i will try bring some more explanation if possible

Comment: There is already a user in the database with the same name which is probably why `-2` is appended at the end of the user profile slug. Your problem might be coming from the fact that you're not handling duplicate users cases, but that's just pondering as I don't have any code in front of me.

Comment: I have created a new user normal test user but still an issue please watch the video I didn't code or used any script normal plugins that I showed in the first video https://www.loom.com/share/bce506b57b8f4aa3926d038e9580795e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Yoast SEO plugin check if the redirect is apply in your customer, or you can check if you subscription plugin have a redirection to the index page.

Comment: Deactivated all plugins instead of wocommerce and elementor and activated WordPress default theme but still redirecting lol seems like redirect stored in the database or what, its weird :/